# eclipse-cdt reference to another project in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C++, so forgive me for basic question.
I have project A (runnable project. project with main). 
I tried to use unit test framework , but i gave up for a meantime, so i tried to test by creating test project.

So i did the following in order to create test project , but dost work (compilation error).
1. create new project with reference to the tested project.
2. in gcc c++ compiler /included directories add the tested project path 
3. in gcc c++ linker / libraries add the debug directory of the debug directory of the tested project. (i know that the tested project is not library project , but just shoot).

getting compilation error of unknown reference when try to use type from the tested project (include added and recognized).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by add linked source folder in the tested project and add filter on this linked source folder in order to filter the main class.